# Installation impossible on MBP2015

Tags: system-installation

I created USB Boot Media with two different methods. Both didn't work.

1. "Create elementary OS Installer.app" with "elementaryos-0.3.2-stable-amd64.20151209.iso"
   This USB Drive doesn't boot on MBP2015 Retina (Not available at Bootprompt)
2. "unetbootin.app" with "elementaryos-0.3.2-stable-amd64.20151209.iso"
   This drive boots but Dialog Windows appear only a quarter. Rest of the Dialog Windows is Outside the Screen. So no Installation is possible

Comment: I am voting to close this question as unclear, I hardly find any question here than your opinion. Please [edit] your question and  avoid your opinions, before that read [How to ask question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

HiDPI displays (like the one in your retina Macbook) aren't yet supported by elementary OS. You won't have a good time trying to install on this hardware.