# Installation issues on Freya (mouse + window size)

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, display, mouse

I tried to install Freya (Dual boot with Windows 8.1) on a Dell Precision M3800 (Screen: 3200x1800, Core i7, 16GB RAM, 512 GB SSD, wireless logitech mouse).

I encountered two problems:

1. The installation window is much bigger than the screen. For example, I do not see the 1/3 of installation window(s). I already used the Windows-Key + Left-Mouse to drag the window, but that does not work on all installation screens.
2. I can move the mouse around the screen but I can not really click on something. The real click happens on a different location. The X coordinate seems identic to my mouse cursor position but the Y coordinate is completely different.

I downloaded the latest Freya version yesterday.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [an answer to a recent question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/3513/3233) HiDPI displays are not supported.

I suspect this is the cause of both issues you're experiencing